# Python 3.11.3 throws error message: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python

The following was the error message thrown
I referred to previous answers on SO, but couldn't get mine solved

```
Python 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

= RESTART: D:\Dora\RCom\TDoc training\py-training-work\Script files\3gpp_scripts\3gpp scripts\script1_download_meta_data.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Dora\RCom\TDoc training\py-training-work\Script files\3gpp_scripts\3gpp scripts\script1_download_meta_data.py", line 92, in autod
    tkldone()
  File "D:\Dora\RCom\TDoc training\py-training-work\Script files\3gpp_scripts\3gpp scripts\script1_download_meta_data.py", line 116, in tkldone
    if "combined_metadata.xlsx" not in os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"meta_refresh_"+dt,l+'_data_'+dt)):
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\Dora\\RCom\\TDoc training\\py-training-work\\Script files\\3gpp_scripts\\3gpp scripts\\meta_refresh_2023-06-05\\R1_data_2023-06-05'
```

INFO
The python script files to be run are stored on D:
Python 3.11 was installed on C:

I tried to run a python script file using Python IDLE. I am getting this error message mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a file at the shown path?

Comment: Yes, the python script file is at the specified D: path.

Comment: Is there a file or directory `D:\Dora\RCom\TDoc training\py-training-work\Script files\3gpp_scripts\3gpp scripts\meta_refresh_2023-06-05\R1_data_2023-06-05`?

Comment: @Michael Butscher, No, there isn't one. Actually, that R1-data_2023-06-05 is the name of the file that will be downloaded as a result of running the script.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory and unambiguous. The file path specified does **not** exist

Comment: @MichaelButscher, however, D:\Dora\RCom\TDoc training\py-training-work\Script files\3gpp_scripts\3gpp scripts --- this one is a valid file/directory

Comment: Aha! So you're trying to run *listdir()* on a non-existent directory. That would explain it

Comment: The script would create that new folder, and save the file in that folder. That's how it works.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't create the folder.

Comment: So, prior to running the file, the folders should be in place?

Comment: Or you check if the folder is present and don't execute code that expects the folder's existence if it isn't there.

Comment: Is that  a filename R1_data_2023-06-05 w/out extensio?

Comment: That should be an excel file generated after the script runs.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, I did some check afterwards. My other query is whether the script files to be run need to be located in the same directory where python was installed (like if python is installed in C:, should script files also be moved to C:?)

Comment: There is no need to store the script files on the same drive or otherwise near the Python installation files.

Comment: Got it resolved! There were few modules to be installed. There was no problems with Python installation, or others. Question can be closed.